# Restriction for duplicate values AngularJS push method

Tags: angularjs, push, addition

Need restriction on entering duplicate values. There is an Add button, user clicks then a text field appears. User inputs the data. AngularJS checks if the data is duplicate or not. If not then a new text field is created. 
This is the strategy.

Intitially, the `val = undefined`. When pushed then array gets the values. But I am wondering how to perform indexOf or any other AngularJS methods in order to maintain duplications.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" ng-click="add(set.values[$index])" value="add">
<span ng-show="message"> Please enter a new value </span> 

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> New valid values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="val in set.values track by $index">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="set.values[$index]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


$scope.set = { values: [] };//array that contains previous ng-model values

$scope.add = function(val) {
  var index = $scope.set.values.indexOf(val);attempt 1
  var index = $scope.set.values.includes(val);attempt 2
  var index = $scope.set.values.indexOf($scope.set.values) 2
  var index = $scope.set.values.includes($scope.set.values) 3
  var index = $scope.set.values.includes($scope.set.values[]) 4

  if (index == false) {
    $scope.message = false;
    $scope.set.values.push('');
  }
  else {
    $scope.message = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you want that the next textfield appears while the user is typing or after he finished typing and clicked on the same button again?

Comment: `ng-click="add(set.values[$index])"` - you wont be getting correct `$index` value there

Comment: @MrWook, I want after he finished typing and clicked on the button

Answer (score 1):

Using angular $filter allows you to extract a given value from an array of values or objects.
Then you can simply check if the filter returned any element.

```
$scope.add = function(val) {    
  return $filter('filter')($scope.set.values, val, true).length;
}
```

remember to inject $filter inside your angular module.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go.

Comment: It doesn't recgonise $filter.

Comment: Did you injected $filter inside your controller/directive/service before using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the last entered value is present in the array or not

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="add"> <span ng-show="message"> Please enter a new value </span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> New valid values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="val in set.values track by $index">
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="set.values[$index]"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.set = {
    values: [" "] //array that contains previous ng-model values & initialize it to empty string
};
$scope.add = function() {
    var length = $scope.set.values.length - 1;
        $scope.newArray=$scope.set.values.slice(-1);//array without last element
        var index = $scope.newArray.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]);
        if (index == -1) {
            $scope.message = false;
            $scope.set.values.push('');
        } else {
            $scope.message = true;
        }
};
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go.

Comment: When I input the second value, $scope.set.values.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]) equals 1 so it $scope.message = false. therefore cannot be procced even when the second field is different than the first field.

Comment: If $scope.set.values.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]) equals 1 then $scope.message=true; . Try with the above answer

Comment: sorry I meant to say $scope.set.values.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]) equals 1 so $scope.message = true when inserting the second text field is added even the values are different.

Comment: after the first value is inserted. When I click the Add button, the value of $scope.newArray.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]) equals to 0 then $scope.message = true;

Comment: Imagine, you want to enter abc. The first click on Add sets $scope.newArray equals to [] and a empty box appears. You enter abc in the field and press Add to add a new field. Now $scope.newArray equals to "abc". Also $scope.set.values[length] equals to abc meaning $scope.newArray.indexOf($scope.set.values[length]) equals 0 therefore the message = true and never creates other text boxes.

Comment: That is what you had asked in the question. So imagine you want to enter abc. So after you enter abc and click add now $scope.newArray will be empty and index==-1 as abc is not present in the empty array. Now imagine if you enter abc again, now $scope.newArray has abc as the only element and $scope.set.values[length] is equal to abc. So index should be 0 and hence message is true and textbox is not created. If this is not what you are looking for , then I suggest you to update the question with proprer problem statement.